# How to use condition IF in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app it's online market. I can add product to cart. I am trying change icon from "add to cart" to "in cart". But it doesn't work correctly. If I add only one product and scroll down, all other products icon also changed. In RecyclerView adapter OnBindViewHolder I use condition if.

I am get data from server in JSON format. And display it in recyclerview. I can add prudact to cart, for this I create table "Busket". When user add product to cart, prudact data added to "Busket". And for example user close the app. And again come back to app, he can find that his added product in other icon and didn't added product in another icon. Ani help. Thank you!

[image: my app image in this link]
My Full adapter.

```
public class PrudactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PrudactAdapter.PrudactViewHolder> {

    List<PrudactModel> prudactsList;
    public Context mContext;
    public static EditPlayerAdapterCallback callback;
    ArrayList<PrudactBusketModel> busketList = new ArrayList<>();
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    public ArrayList<Integer> tableBasket = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> tableFavorite = new ArrayList<>();
    String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public PrudactAdapter(List<PrudactModel> persons, Context context){
        this.prudactsList = persons;
        this.mContext = context;


    }

    @Override
    public PrudactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_of_pruduct, parent, false);
        PrudactViewHolder pvh = new PrudactViewHolder(v,mContext);

        return pvh;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);


    }

    @Override
    public void  onBindViewHolder(final PrudactViewHolder prudactViewHolder, final int i) {

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        final PrudactModel p  = prudactsList.get(i);
        prudactViewHolder.catalogName.setText(p.getName());
        prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setText(Integer.toString(p.getPrice())+" тг");
        prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setText(Integer.toString(p.getOldPrice())+" тг");
        prudactViewHolder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(p.getImgId(),imageLoader);
      //  final MediaPlayer addSound = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.button28);
        //// TODO Cheking PRICE

        if (p.getOldPrice()==0){
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.aksia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black));
        }
        else {
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.aksia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //// TODO Cheking DB

        if (getTableBasket().contains(p.getId()))
            prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool);
        else
            prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool1);

        if (getTableFavorite().contains(p.getId()))
            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_d);
        else
            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_c);

        //// TODO: 02.05.2016  BUY BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.tool1).getConstantState()){
                    updateBuyButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("basket", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to basket inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                    callback.folderClicked(1);
                }
                else {
                    updateBuyButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    callback.folderClicked(-1);
                    db.delete("basket","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
                }
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.tool1).getConstantState()){
                    updateBuyButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("basket", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to basket inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                    callback.folderClicked(1);
                }
                else {
                    updateBuyButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    callback.folderClicked(-1);
                    db.delete("basket","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
                }
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });

       //// TODO: 02.05.2016  FAVORITE BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.favorite_c).getConstantState()){
                    updateHeartButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("favorite", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to favorite inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                }

                else {
                    updateHeartButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    db.delete("favorite","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
               }
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.favorite_c).getConstantState()){
                    updateHeartButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("favorite", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to favorite inserted, ID = " + rowID);

                }
                else {
                    updateHeartButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    db.delete("favorite","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
               }
            }
        });

        //// TODO: 02.05.2016  SHARE BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String shareBody = "Мне нравится "+p.getName()+" за "+p.getPrice()+" тенге. unimax.kz";
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Elaman" ));
            }
        });
        prudactViewHolder.btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String shareBody = "Мне нравится "+p.getName()+" за "+p.getPrice()+" тенге. unimax.kz";
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Elaman" ));
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.thumbNail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image",p.getImgId());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        dbHelper.close();

    }



    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return prudactsList.size();
    }

    public void setCallback(EditPlayerAdapterCallback callback2){

        callback = callback2;
    }

    public static class PrudactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CardView cv;
        TextView catalogName,catalogPrice,catalogPriceOld;
        NetworkImageView thumbNail;
        ImageButton btn_favorite,btn_share, btn_buy;
        LinearLayout ll_buy,aksia,ll_share,ll_favorite;

        public PrudactViewHolder(View itemView,Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            catalogName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_catalog);
            catalogPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_catalog);
            catalogPriceOld = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.old_price_catalog);

            btn_buy = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);
            btn_share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
            btn_favorite = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.izbrannyi);

            thumbNail = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_catalog);
            aksia = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aksia);
            ll_buy = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_buy);
            ll_share = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_share);
            ll_favorite = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_favorite);

            catalogPriceOld.setPaintFlags(catalogPriceOld.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        }
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> getTableBasket(){

        ArrayList<Integer> id_list = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("basket", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int id_prudactColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id_prudact");
            do {
                id_list.add(c.getInt(id_prudactColIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In basket 0 rows");
        c.close();

        return id_list;
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> getTableFavorite(){

        ArrayList<Integer> id_list = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("favorite", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int id_prudactColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id_prudact");
            do {
                id_list.add(c.getInt(id_prudactColIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In favorite 0 rows");
        c.close();

        return id_list;
    }
}
```

my db structure

```
db.execSQL("create table basket ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "id_prudact integer,"
                + "name text,"
                + "id_image integer,"
                + "count integer,"
                + "price integer,"
                + "priceOld integer,"
                + "nomer_zakaz text" + ");");

        db.execSQL("create table favorite ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "id_prudact integer,"
                + "name text,"
                + "id_image text,"
                + "count integer,"
                + "price integer,"
                + "priceOld integer" + ");");
```

MY UPDATE CODE

```
public class PrudactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PrudactAdapter.PrudactViewHolder> {

    List<PrudactModel> prudactsList;
    public Context mContext;
    public static EditPlayerAdapterCallback callback;
    ArrayList<PrudactBusketModel> busketList = new ArrayList<>();
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    ArrayList<Integer> tableBasket = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> tableFavorite = new ArrayList<>();
    String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public PrudactAdapter(List<PrudactModel> persons, Context context){
        this.prudactsList = persons;
        this.mContext = context;
        tableBasket = getTableBasket();
        tableFavorite = getTableFavorite();
    }

    @Override
    public PrudactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_of_pruduct, parent, false);
        PrudactViewHolder pvh = new PrudactViewHolder(v,mContext);

        return pvh;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);


    }

    @Override
    public void  onBindViewHolder(final PrudactViewHolder prudactViewHolder, final int i) {

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        final PrudactModel p  = prudactsList.get(i);
        prudactViewHolder.catalogName.setText(p.getName());
        prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setText(Integer.toString(p.getPrice())+" тг");
        prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setText(Integer.toString(p.getOldPrice())+" тг");
        prudactViewHolder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(p.getImgId(),imageLoader);
      //  final MediaPlayer addSound = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.button28);
        //// TODO Cheking PRICE

        if (p.getOldPrice()==0){
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.aksia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black));
        }
        else {
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.aksia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //// TODO Cheking DB


        if (tableBasket.contains(p.getId())){
            Log.d("pa","id "+ p.getId());
            prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool);}
        else
            prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool1);

        if (tableFavorite.contains(p.getId()))
            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_d);
        else
            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_c);

        //// TODO: 02.05.2016  BUY BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.tool1).getConstantState()){
                    updateBuyButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("basket", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to basket inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                    callback.folderClicked(1);
                }
                else {
                    updateBuyButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    callback.folderClicked(-1);
                    db.delete("basket","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
                }
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.tool1).getConstantState()){
                    updateBuyButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("basket", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to basket inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                    callback.folderClicked(1);
                }
                else {
                    updateBuyButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    callback.folderClicked(-1);
                    db.delete("basket","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
                }
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });

       //// TODO: 02.05.2016  FAVORITE BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.favorite_c).getConstantState()){
                    updateHeartButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("favorite", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to favorite inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                }

                else {
                    updateHeartButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    db.delete("favorite","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
               }
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.favorite_c).getConstantState()){
                    updateHeartButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("favorite", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to favorite inserted, ID = " + rowID);

                }
                else {
                    updateHeartButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    db.delete("favorite","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
               }
            }
      }    
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return prudactsList.size();
    }

    public void setCallback(EditPlayerAdapterCallback callback2){

        callback = callback2;
    }

    public static class PrudactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CardView cv;
        TextView catalogName,catalogPrice,catalogPriceOld;
        NetworkImageView thumbNail;
        ImageButton btn_favorite,btn_share, btn_buy;
        LinearLayout ll_buy,aksia,ll_share,ll_favorite;

        public PrudactViewHolder(View itemView,Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            catalogName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_catalog);
            catalogPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_catalog);
            catalogPriceOld = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.old_price_catalog);

            btn_buy = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);
            btn_share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
            btn_favorite = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.izbrannyi);

            thumbNail = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_catalog);
            aksia = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aksia);
            ll_buy = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_buy);
            ll_share = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_share);
            ll_favorite = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_favorite);

            catalogPriceOld.setPaintFlags(catalogPriceOld.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        }


    }

     ArrayList<Integer> getTableBasket(){

        ArrayList<Integer> id_list = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("basket", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int id_prudactColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id_prudact");
            do {
                id_list.add(c.getInt(id_prudactColIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In basket 0 rows");
        c.close();

        return id_list;
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> getTableFavorite(){

        ArrayList<Integer> id_list = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("favorite", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int id_prudactColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id_prudact");
            do {
                id_list.add(c.getInt(id_prudactColIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In favorite 0 rows");
        c.close();

        return id_list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `add to cart` Button?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK add to cart button it is btn_buy button

Comment: @eluuu: As in current code  `getTableBasket()` and `getTableFavorite()` methods will call many times when getView method called. so instead of access db again-2 for same data just get data from both table in `PrudactAdapter ` class constructor and store it in ArrayList, then use it inside getView method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I did it, but when I add some prudact to cart and scroll and come back to added prudact I find it *not added*

Comment: @eluuu: show your updated code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I updated my code